# should be true keyword in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Want to validate 10 arguments using **should be true** keyword.

```
should be true    ${M1}==${M2}==${M3}==${M4}==${M5}==${M6}==${M7}==${M8}==${M9}==${M10}   PROFSU_LC_RES_START_DEINIT_PersDataAndFS is ${M1}
        ...  \nFSLC fs_lc_priv_deinit_fat32 : ### Unmount second Reliance Edge ..Data-resrc-rw is ${M2}\nFSLC fs_lc_priv_deinit_fat32 : ### Unmount third Reliance Edge partition Logistic ..Data-resrc-rw2  is ${M3}
        ...  \nPROFSU_PERS_EMMC_UNMOUNTED is ${M4}
        ...  \nPROFSU_LC_RES_END_DEINIT_PersDataAndFS is ${M5}\nPROFSU_LC_RES_START_INIT_PersDataAndFS is ${M6}
        ...  \nFSLC fs_lc_priv_init_redfs2 : .* ..Data-resrc-rw is ${M7}\nFSLC fs_lc_priv_init_redfs2 : .* ..Data-resrc-rw2 is ${M8}
        ...  \nPROFSU_PERS_EMMC_MOUNTED is ${M9}\nPROFSU_LC_RES_END_INIT_PersDataAndFS is ${M10}
```

Is this the right approach??

I am getting result in console as "BuiltIn.Should Be True' expected 1 to 2 arguments, got 8"

Comment: "Should be True" typically takes one argument as condition e.g. '${STATUS}'=='PASS' and optional argument for a message. I don't understand exactly what it is you're doing from the code but maybe you can do "Should Be True" for each statement separately

Comment: Thanks @MatthewKing for your response

Comment: Thanks @MatthewKing for your response.  I tried actually  with Should be True condition with multiple arguments as:   Should be True Condition1==Condition2  first condition is ${Condition1}\n second condition is ${Condition2}

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and assigned 2 to arguments. The code ran without errors. So your approach seems right

```
Set Test Variable    ${M1}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M2}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M3}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M4}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M5}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M6}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M7}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M8}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M9}    ${2}
Set Test Variable    ${M10}    ${2}
Should Be True    ${M1}==${M2}==${M3}==${M4}==${M5}==${M6}==${M7}==${M8}==${M9}==${M10}
```

I suspect that the problem is in your arguments. You can try to validate your arguments in For loop, you can use Keywords **Should Be Equal**, **Should Be Equal As String** and so on, depending on your arguments

```
    @{arguments}=    Create List
    Append To List    ${arguments}   ${M1}    ${M2}    ${M3}    ${M4}    ${M5}    ${M6}    ${M7}    ${M8}    ${M9}    ${M10}
    FOR    ${arg}    IN    @{arguments}
        Should Be Equal    ${M1}    ${arg}
    END
```